# How can I find x and z if: $\sqrt{(x-20)^{2} + (5-30)^{2} + (z-40)^{2}} = 100$ and $x \sqrt\frac{1}{6} + 5\sqrt\frac{1}{3} + z \sqrt\frac12= 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, radicals

How can I find x and z if:

$\sqrt{((x-20)^{2} + (5-30)^{2} + (z-40)^{2})} = 100$ and $\left(x\times \sqrt\frac{1}{6} + 5\times \sqrt\frac{1}{3} + z\times \sqrt\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0$ ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've tried a lot. For the left equation I get x = 55 - z, although I am not sure. For the right one I get x = (30.967 - zSqrt(1/2)) / Sqrt(1/6). The I'm trying to find z with 55 - z = (30.967 - zSqrt(1/2)) / Sqrt(1/6) but I'm stuck at -z = (30.967 - zSqrt(1/2)) / Sqrt(1/6) - 55.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we have
$$(x-20)^2+(z-40)^2=100^2-25^2$$
$$x=-\sqrt 3z-5\sqrt 2$$
we have
$$(-\sqrt 3z-5\sqrt 2-20)^2+(z-40)^2=100^2-25^2.$$
Expand these to get the form $Az^2+Bz+C=0$ and use
$$z=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}.$$

P.S. Multiplying the both sides of 
$$x\times\sqrt{\frac 16}+5\times\sqrt{\frac 13}+z\times\sqrt{\frac 12}=0$$
by $\sqrt 6$ gives us
$$x\times\frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt 6}+5\times\frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt 3}+z\times\frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt 2}=0$$
i.e.
$$x+5\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3z=0\Rightarrow x=-\sqrt 3z-5\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you (comments must be minimum 15 chars...)

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: I added a bit. Have a look.

Comment: Yea thanks. Actually, I figured out how you made it and deleted my comment. Now I'm trying to understand how you went from the first two lines to the third but I'll probably be ok by myself now. Thanks though.

Comment: I can't understand how one can expand the third line to get the form Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0, if you don't mind explaining it to me?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: Do you know how to expand $(a+b)^2$ ?

Comment: I just found out on internet, so yes.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron: Then, you can use it and take $(-\sqrt 3z-5\sqrt 2-20)^2=(a+b)^2$ where $a=-\sqrt 3z,b=-5\sqrt 2-20$.